# HTML file not displaying browser

Tags: html, browser

lately I've been having a problem, where I try to open my html file in any browser but it doesn't display and it's stuck in a state of loading, i've tried opening another html file and putting the same code but it doesn't display. I suspect it's a problem with the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="learn.css" />
    <script src="learn.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:image/png;base64,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">
    <title>Jordan Jana</title>
</head>
<body id="b0dy">
    <nav class="crumble">
        <ol class="crumb">
            <button class="butt" style="color: #64ffda;">
            <a style="text-decoration: none" href="me.html">About me</a>
        </button>
        </ol>
    </nav class="nav">
    <p id="potsu">
    Hi, I'm
    </p>
    <br>
    <div id="para"><p>Jordan</p>
    </div>
    <div id="surname"><p>Jana</p></div>
    <div id="me"><p>I love making stuff(online not in real life)<br>
    I'm currently learning Web Development and a bit of bash on the side.<br>
I also have a <a href="https://github.com/K5tsu">Github</a>,<a href="https://twitter.com/J0rdanJana">Twitter</a>,
and discord(senpai-kun#3773) where I'm most active and you're more likely to reach me</p></div>
<div id="and"><p>And</p></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried changing browsers and changing some of the code but the problem persists

Comment: checked your code in fiddle and it works fine. However one thing - you have a typo in your code - the closing tag on `nav` element, cannot have a class name.

Comment: Note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Checked your code in multiple browsers it is working fine, Try to refresh the webpage by CTRL+F5. if issue still persists then there is an issue with your javascript.
and also don't use classes on endings of tags like you did with

```
</nav class="nav">
```

Comment: Thank you, it was a problem with my javascript